# Error Invalid regular expression: Metro Bundler process exited with code 1

Tags: react-native

Every project was working fine untill this Err. I dont know this is due to node upgrade; I tried by downgrading node from latest to stable version but nothing work !! 
I run my react native project with *yarn start*

```
Err: error Invalid regular expression: /(.*\\__fixtures__\\.*|node_modules[\\\]react[\\\]dist[\\\].*|website\\node_modules\\.*|heapCapture\\bundle\.js|.*\\__tests__\\.*)$/: Unterminated character class. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Metro Bundler process exited with code 1
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
```

Comment: just delete the node modules folder of your app, then in the project directory run yarn install and the new node modules will be made ,  after that try to run 'yarn start'

Comment: tried this but not after downgrading node. let me do that again

Comment: what is your node version?

Comment: before downgrading > 13.3 and right now > 12.13.1

Comment: tried deleting node modules but nothing works

Comment: no need to downgrade, just follow the answer below

Comment: now the directory is been updated to `node_modules -> metro -> src -> blacklist`

Answer (score 2):

Go to node_modules -> metro-config -> src -> defaults -> blacklist.js

Find this array:

```
   var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[/\\]react[/\\]dist[/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\
  ];
```

And replace it with this

```
   var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\
  ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Things seem to have changed since the previous answer which doesn't work. Open file PROJECT_NAME\node_modules\metro-config\src\defaults\blacklist.js
and replace the current `var sharedBlacklist` to this:

`var sharedBlacklist = [/node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,/website\/node_modules\/.*/,/heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,/.*\/__tests__\/.*/];`

Answer (score 1):

go to this file node_modules > metro-config > src > defaults > blacklist.js

and find

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[/\\]react[/\\]dist[/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

And update with this

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```